# Efficiently finding all points dominated by a point in 2D

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computational-geometry

In the OCW [Advanced Data Structures course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-851-advanced-data-structures-spring-2012/index.htm), Prof. E. Demaine mentions a Data Structure that is able to find all the points dominated by a query point (b<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>3</sub>) using O(n) space and O(k) time, provided that a search for point b<sub>3</sub> has already been completed, where k is the size of the output.

The solution works by transforming the above problem into a ray stabbing problem, and using a technique similar to fractional cascading, as shown in the following [image from the lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-851-advanced-data-structures-spring-2012/calendar-and-notes/MIT6_851S12_Lec4.pdf):

[image: Finding all points dominated by (b<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>3</sub>).]

While the concept itself is intuitive, implementing the actual data structure is not straightforward at all.

Chazelle describes this in a paper as [Filtering Search (pp712)](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/FilteringSearch.pdf).

I would like to find additional literature or answers that describe and explain of this data structure and algorithm (perhaps with pseudo code and more images, with focus on implementation).

Additionally, I would also like to know more about whether this structure can be implemented in a way that is not "static".  That is, I would like to be able to insert and delete points from the structure as efficiently as possible.

Comment: What is "dominated by"?

Comment: A point (a_2, a_3) is dominated by (b_2, b_3) if (informally)  (a_2, a_3) can be found in the quadrant to the lower-left of point (b_2, b_3).  More formally, if a_2 <= b_2 and a_3 <= b_3.

Answer (score 3):

The book ["Computational Geometry: Algorithms and Applications"](http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/) covers data structures for questions like these. Each chapter has a nice section describing where to learn more, including more complex structures for answering the same problems that are not covered in the book. There are enough diagrams, but not much pseudocode.

Many structures like this can be dynamized using techniques discussed in the book "The design of dynamic data structures". [Jeff Erickson has some nice notes on the topic.](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/datastructures/notes/01-statictodynamic.pdf) Using fractional cascading with it is discussed is [Cache-Oblivious Streaming B-trees"](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/papers/sbtree.pdf) - see the section about "cache-oblivious lookahead arrays.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the useful links! It certainly takes a lot of time to go through them all - and I'm still reading.  I especially liked the notes that describe an alternative way to deal with decomposable search problems.  I'm not sure if I've encountered the exact problem I was describing above however (although I might have missed it).